# JPA 2-way manytomany relation

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have a Spring boot 2 application (3.1.0). In this application I have a 2-way ManyToMany association. I call it 2-way because in both classes I have a ManyToMany annotation. The classes are Product and Category. Product can have multiple category and vice verse.

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<Category> categories;

}

public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Product> products;

}
```

When I create a product and fill the categories list, with 2 existing categories that I have loaded from the database, the "Join Table" that attaches the product and category stays empty. It doesn't attach the product with the 2 existing categories.

When I remove the products list in Category so that it essentially becomes a 1-way many to many (Product has a list of categories) then it does work. What I am guessing is that the Product is saved first and then it saves the categories association and since their manytomany is empty it then empties the "Join Table".

How can I solve this? I need the many to many in both classes and if I save the Product it should save the list of categories it has and if I save the category it should save the product list it has.